# Postscript in R: How to remove a large left margin (on y axis)

Tags: r, data-visualization, barplot

I have a problem. I am creating a wide barplot (50x grouped 4 columns) and printing it to ps. However the figure does not fit to printed ps - the x axis goes out of a page. It would fit if only I could remove a large left margin on yaxis. But I have no idea how to move picture left and reduce the margin. I have spend some time on asking uncle google but I have not found anything. Could somebody help me?

Here is my R script:

```
mx <- matrix( c(5,3,8,9,5,3,8,9),nr=4)

postscript(file="<fileName>.ps");

barplot(mx, beside=T,  col=gray.colors(4), cex.axis = 1.4, cex.names=1.2, xlim=c(1,60), width=0.264,  xaxs = "r", yaxs = "r")

legend("topleft", c( "A1",  "A2","B1","B2"), pch=15, 
        cex=1.1,
       col=gray.colors(4), 
       bty="n")
```

Comment: Can you construct a simple, reproducible example of your problem? Just now I can't reproduce your difficultly since I don't have `mx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quite like the suggestion made by [Andrew Gelman](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2010/10/could_someone_p.html) for the default setting of `par`. Namely,

```
par(mar=c(3,3,2,1), mgp=c(2,.7,0), tck=-.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the help page of function **par**:

`mar`: A numerical vector of the form `c(bottom, left, top, right)`
          which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on
          the four sides of the plot.  The default is `c(5, 4, 4, 2) +
          0.1`.

So try something like

```
par(mar=c(5,1,4,2))
```

before calling **barplot**.

Comment: It's usually considered good practice to save the old parameters before modifying them, so that new settings don't propagate throughout successive calls to `plot.*` functions. An example of use would be: `opar <- par(mar=c(5,1,4,2)); ... plotting goes here ...; par(opar)`.

Comment: @chl, OP uses postscript, so the plotting must end with dev.off(). This resets all the par settings. The same holds for usual plots. If dev.off is called between plot's, settings are reseted.

Comment: That's right. Sorry about that (forgot about the PS issue).

Comment: @chl, nothing to be sorry about, au contraire, your comment was useful, since this is good to know if you indent to use par more often.

Answer (score 2):

You could look after the par() function's mar(gin) paramater. A nice brief can be found in [efg's Research Notes](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm).